# flexible rows with no scrollbar depend on browser resize

Tags: css, html

//my browser is latest version of Chorme//

I have 3 rows of boxes:

First box is `<div>` with fixed height and 100% width.

second box is `<video>` with variable height (dependent on browser size) and (if possible 100% width - dependent on height)

third box is `<div>` with fixed height and 100% width.

These 3 boxes are in body tag...and body section must fill full webpage flexibility depend on browser size.

I want when I resize browser manually,the second box resized automaicly...I do not want shows me scrollbar in row or columns instead resizing...
I could not arrange these rows...

**Normaly All boxes are in max their width and height...but not bigger current open browser windows with each sizes**

I tried this code:

```
<body>
<div class="videos">
<div class="topbox">The top text box</div>
<video class="videos1" controls>
    <source src="http://dinamit.ir/test/dinamit.mp4"  type="video/mp4"  />
    <source src="http://dinamit.ir/test/dinamit.webm" type="video/webm" />
</video>
<div class="bottombox">The bottom text box</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Also code is here:http://jsfiddle.net/BBGYU/4/
(you can see scrollbar in this example - I do not want scrollbar or hidden overflow content....I want resize middle content automaticly)

--please resize result box top-down in http://jsfiddle.net/BBGYU/4/ to better underestand my means.

Comment: overflow: hidden; in the body ? Or give at your div with fixed heigth also fixed position ( top: 0 - bottom:0 ) and at your video div heigth: 100%

Comment: You can see here the result: http://jsfiddle.net/BBGYU/6/   no works